# How can I call keySet() method of HashMap in jstl?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I am passing a HashMap to my jsp. There I need to fetch the key values from the map, in jstl. something like

```
<c:set var="set" value="${fn:valueMap.keySet()}"></c:set>
```

and get individual values from the map using get() method. I cannot use a < c:foreach> to iterate the map due to the particular presentation logic.

Comment: Maybe you could just resort to a good ole JSP code block?

Comment: why you arent passing the set to the jsp ?

Comment: @Josef Procházka: That means I have to pass the the set and map (for getting values) separately to the jsp rt?